# obtain multiple "background-image" style on Android (2.3.x)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css

I have an element with multiple background images like this:

### HTML

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

### CSS

```
div {
  ...
  background-image: url("img1"), url("img2"), url("img3");
  background-size: 30px 30px, 30px 30px, 30px 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom left, bottom center, bottom right;
}
```

Now I want to get "background-image" style value, so I tried to do the following:

### JavaScript

```
bgImg = $("#myDiv").css("background-image");
console.log(bgImg); // expect -> url("img1"), url("img2"), url("img3")
```

It works well on Chrome / Firefox / Safari on Mac OS.

However, with default browser on Android (OS 2.3.x),
it outputs the first background-image element.

```
url("img1")
```

Does anyone know why and how to obtain multiple "background-image" value on
Android's default browser?

### Sample Code

http://jsfiddle.net/kakipo/r3HMF/1/

(For mobile access: http://jsfiddle.net/kakipo/r3HMF/1/show)